# Tableau, cannot further aggregate

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api, calculated-field

Reading this tutorial on [creating normal curve on Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/s/blog/2013/11/fitting-normal-curve-histogram)

I am trying to create Standard Deviation calculated field for Average Ratings of each Location (Average rating is written on heat map):

[image]

Creating the mean was easy, because I already have following:

```
Mean = Total(AVG([Number_Rating]))
```

And I can create standard deviation

```
St Dev = TOTAL ( STDEV ( [Number_Rating] ) )
```

But I have difficulty creating curve

```
Curve = (1/(sqrt([St Dev]^2*2*pi()))) * exp(-( (attr([Rating Bin Size])-[Mean])^2  /  (2*[St Dev]^2)  )) 
* [Rating Bin Size]
* TOTAL(SUM([Occurrence_Location]))
```

Occurrence_Location is the number of Locations, i.e. `CountD([Location])`. Error is

```
Argument to SUM (an aggregate function) is already an aggregation, and cannot be further aggregated.
```

How to fix this? Workbook on [Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/BellCurveBusinessRating/Grade), tab of interest is `Grade` and `Histogram`

Comment: This is a limitation of Tableau. It is possible to work around it if you have a data source that supports calculations external to Tableau, but then you cannot port your workbook between datasources or save with extracts.

Comment: How is [Occurrence Location] aggregated? COUNTD([Location]), or is it an LOD expression?

Comment: @CharlieHaley It is `CountD[Location]`

Comment: Then I would think your SUM here is redundant.  Either that or you should be using an LOD expression instead of CUM(COUNTD([Location]))

Answer (score 1):

If the calculated field has aggregation inside, Tableau doesn't let you aggregate it again. 
You may try using window aggregation such as **window_Avg**.

For example:

**First Calculation:**     Profit Ratio

sum([profit])/sum([Sales])               //Aggregate Calc

**Second Calc:**     Avg of Profit Ratio

window_avg([Profit Ratio])               //Table Calc

For more reference [read this page.](https://community.tableau.com/thread/135269)